# Getting the Monthwise count from date column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that consists of the following data, I would like to know whether it is possible to get a Month (i.e Jan, Feb) wise count of Reservations that happened and also Month wise count for each location.

| PNR | Location | Reservation Date | Passenger Name | Travel Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PNR81239087 | Mumbai | 2019-10-01 12:19:00 | Ram | 2019-11-06 15:59:00 |
| PNR81239090 | Kerala | 2019-10-01 15:18:00 | Kannan | 2019-12-03 19:18:00 |
| PNR812390199 | Mumbai | 2019-10-01 17:19:00 | Ram | 2019-11-01 18:39:00 |

For example,

**Month Wise Count (including all locations)** should look something like this,

| Month | Count |
| --- | --- |
| October-2019 | 3 |

**Monthwise count for each location:**

| Month | Count | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| October-2019 | 2 | Mumbai |
| October-2019 | 1 | Kerala |

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What seems to be a problem?

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work for you

### Month Wise Count (including all locations) :

```
select MONTHNAME(Reservation_Date) as Month, count(*)
from yourTable
group by MONTHNAME(Reservation_Date)
```

### Monthwise count for each location :

```
select MONTHNAME(Reservation_Date) as Month, count(*), Location
from yourTable
group by MONTHNAME(Reservation_Date), Location
```

## EDIT IN QUESTION :

Changed to Group by Year and Month in one column:

### Month Wise Count (including all locations) :

```
select concat(MONTHNAME(Reservation_Date),'-',Year(Reservation_Date)) as Month-Year,
       count(*) as Count
from yourTable
group by concat(MONTHNAME(Reservation_Date),'-',Year(Reservation_Date))
```

### Monthwise count for each location :

```
select concat(MONTHNAME(Reservation_Date),'-',Year(Reservation_Date)) as Month-Year,
       count(*) as Count, Location
from yourTable
group by concat(MONTHNAME(Reservation_Date),'-',Year(Reservation_Date)), Location
```

Comment: Possible to add year also next to the month in both the queries? Like October-2019

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
/*Location-wise*/
SELECT      DATENAME(MONTH, ReservationDate) as [Month],
            COUNT(*) AS Count,
            Location
FROM        Temp
GROUP BY    DATENAME(MONTH, ReservationDate), Location
ORDER BY    Location DESC

/*All locations*/
SELECT      DATENAME(MONTH, ReservationDate) as [Month],
            COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM        Temp
GROUP BY    DATENAME(MONTH, ReservationDate)
```

You can see this working here : [All locations](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5ff37/5) and [Locations-wise](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5ff37/6)

Comment: This is giving an error "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Month],"